# jquery selector "contains" making error while using in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-selectors

I want to find whether the text in the input field contains any space character.For that I use the statement

```
$("#myTextBox").val().trim().contains(" ");
```

this should return `true` if the text in the textbox contains any space. But the problem is this is not working in Chrome and IE. It returns an error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` in chrome's console. While in Firefox it is working fine.
What would be the probable reason. Is it curable?

Please find the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1L1pf7c7/3/

Comment: the "contains" method is part of the ECMAScript 6 proposal, it's not standard yet and it is not supported in every browser. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `indexOf(' ')` with value to check space/whitespace character existence

```
if($("#myTextBox").val().indexOf(' ')>=0){
  //space exists
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1m72adzx/)**

Comment: thankyou.. this worked. But I found that this is a javascript function. Is there any jquery methods for this without checking whether the index is greater than 0.

Comment: you should not be doing something extra in jquery when pure javascript provide easy functionality :)